# Filter a collection with a custom attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, collection, filter, eav

I'm trying to add a custom attribute to the customer_entity table and then sort the collection with that custom attribute.

So far I've tried using etc/db_schema.xml to add a column to the table, and even though the column got added to the table, `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('my_custom_attribute', '1')` returned 'attribute 'my_custom_attribute' is invalid'.

I then tried to create a data patch, following various example online, to add an eav attribute. Here's my patch :

```php
<?php

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchInterface;

class AddMagasinAttributeToCustomer implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /** @var EavSetupFactory */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magasin', [
            'type' => 'int',
        ]);

    }
}
```

Now the eav attribute is present in the customer_eav_attribute table. I updated some customer data with the custom attribute value set to 1, but now, `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('my_custom_attribute', '1')` returns an empty array.

I have dumped the value of the corresponding record without any filter and the custom attribute value is set in the table.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `$collection->addFilter('my_custom_attribute', my_custom_value)` returns the correct filtered data. I still don't know why the other method does not work though.